# If and API returns an error it means that the request has failed. There is never a possibility that is means it has been delayed?

Tags: api

If an API responds with any error (500, 400, 0) it means that the requests has failed and is save to repeat it? It can never mean that the response has been delayed and will arrive later?

Comment: If a response is sent, that response is sent. Usually, it's not possible that an API will send a different response at any later time without senidng a new request

Comment: Hi Nico,
thank you for your answer. Let's say I am sending an SQL command to my server. The command will take time to execute. But the response 200 will be send immediately after the server validates the payload and not after the execution is completed, right?

Comment: That depends on your API. Also, feel free to add all clarification to your question by editing it